# what does the 'set -g' command do in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I see references to `set -g <command>` in tmux, for example

```
set -g status-right ' #[bg=colour33] Branch #[(git branch)] '
```

I have googled and looked in `man tmux` and also `info tmux` but cant find any info.

what does `set -g` do?
does it set a variable in the same way that vim uses `:set <variable>` ?
If so what does the `-g` do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### What does the 'set -g' command do in tmux?

- `set` is an alias for `set-option`.
- `-g` is used to set the option for the global session or window.

> Commands which set options are as follows:
>
> `set-option [-agoqsuw] [-t target-session | target-window] option
>   value (alias: set)`
>
> Set a window option with `-w` (equivalent to the `set-window-option`
>   command), a server option with `-s`, otherwise a session option.
>
> If `-g` is specified, the global session or window option is set.

Source [tmux — terminal multiplexer](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/tmux.1.html)

Comment: Great answer, thanks! yes once you know `set` is an alias for *set-option* then it makes sense, i.e. There are options applied at a global level, which may or many not be inherited by the option state of the `session` and `window`. I wish I had more rep so I could upvote this answer!

Comment: Yes, power must have been diverted from the shields just long enough to give me the rep gravity boost I needed to upvote!  upvoted :)